# How could I make this script output to a text file?

Tags: php

Lets say I wanted to have this script output to a text file called "text1", how would I go about this?

```
<?php
$friends = array("Mike Lark" => "Islip", "Nick Miller"=>"Valley Stream", "James Allen"=>"Los Angeles", "John D"=>"New York");

foreach($friends as $friend => $town){
echo "<tr><td>$friend</td> > <td>$town</tr><BR>";
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: I don't think you want `<BR>`'s in your text file, but linefeeds which is better.

Comment: btw; any special reason why you're not using a database for this?

Comment: you also should be gettings errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative, without replacing `echo` statements with variable concatenations is to use output buffers.

With this you can catch everything that was printed with echo and then save to file:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // start an output buffer

  echo "<head><title>Friends & Hometowns</title></head>";
  echo "<h1>List of Friends & Their Hometowns</h1>"; 


$friends = array("Mike Lark" => "Islip", "Nick Miller"=>"Valley Stream", "James Allen"=>"Los Angeles", "John D"=>"New York");

foreach($friends as $friend => $town){
echo "<tr><td>$friend</td> > <td>$town</tr><BR>";
}
echo "</table>";

$output = ob_get_clean(); // extract everything that has been buffered
file_put_contents('output.txt', $output); // save it to file
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents('file.txt', $friend."</td> > <td>".$town."</tr><BR>",  FILE_APPEND);`

Use FILE_APPEND instead including file, check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to include the file to write it, the following code will work just fine:

Also if you echo then that echo does not go into the file.
You need to add up all data in a variable say $result and then finally write it to the file:

```
<?php
  $result = "";
  $result.="<head><title>Friends & Hometowns</title></head>";
  $result.="<h1>List of Friends & Their Hometowns</h1>";    
  $friends = array("Mike Lark" => "Islip", "Nick Miller"=>"Valley Stream", "James Allen"=>"Los Angeles", "John D"=>"New York");

foreach($friends as $friend => $town){
    $result.="<tr><td>$friend</td> > <td>$town</tr><BR>";
}
$result.="</table>";
file_put_contents('file.txt', $result);
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

As @Ahmed Rezk Suggested if you do not want to erase existing data in the file use the `FILE_APPEND` flag of file_put_contents(); like:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $result, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be "MVC"'ed.

```
##Model.php
<?php
$friends = array("Mike Lark" => "Islip", "Nick Miller"=>"Valley Stream", "James Allen"=>"Los Angeles", "John D"=>"New York");

##View.php
<head><title>Friends & Hometowns</title></head>
<h1>List of Friends & Their Hometowns</h1>
<?php
foreach($friends as $friend => $town){ ?>
   <tr><td><?=$friend?></td>  <td><?=$town?></tr>
<?php 
}
?>

##Controller.php
<?php
require_once "Model.php";
require_once "View.php";
```

that's it. Your codes are cleaner, have separations of concerns. Your IDE can give you better intellisense on your HTML and PHP codes.

After this, you can follow the answer by @Ibrahim for the output buffer stuff.

Disclaimer: this is basic MVC, and this can be improved of course. however, this is far better than echoing html all over the place.